# Error while Testing Create with Mocha,Chai, Node.JS and MongoSB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

I am learning about testing with Mocha and setting up a few simple tests for an application. My first two test work but I keep getting an error for the last test.

The error message is : 2 passing (87ms)

> 1 failing
>
> 1) Routing Tests ## Create article  should create a task:
>        Uncaught AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Test Title'
>         at Test. (test/todos.test.js:33:39)
>         at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:179:6)
>         at Server.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
>         at emitCloseNT (net.js:1646:8)
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Here is the error I am getting from the databse.

> Validation is failing:{ ValidationError: Article validation failed:
>   title: Path `title` is required.
>       at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/patrickbentley/Desktop/Article-Scraper/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:57:23)

Here is my test:

```
describe('## Create article ', function() { 
 it('should create a task', function(done) { 
  request(app) .post('/saved') .send({"title":'Test Title'}) 
 .end(function(err, res) { 
    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200); 
    expect(res.body.title).to.equal('Test Title'); 
    task = res.body; 
    done(); 
  }); 
 }); 
});
```

Here is my Model:

```
// Require mongoose
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
// Create Schema class
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create article schema
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
// title is a required string
title: {
 type: String,
 required: true
},
// link is a required string
link: {
type: String
},
// This only saves one note's ObjectId, ref refers to the Note model
note: {
 type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: "Note"
}
});

// Create the Article model with the ArticleSchema
var Article = mongoose.model("Article", ArticleSchema);

// Export the model
module.exports = Article;
```

Here is my code for the '/saved' route:

```
router.post("/saved", function(req,res){
var entry = new Article(
    {
        title:req.body.title
    });
entry.save(function(err, doc) {
    // Log any errors
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    // Or log the doc
    else {
      console.log(doc);
    }
  });
  res.render('index');
});
```

So, I know that my format for the post action is wrong in my test, but I dont know what it is.

Comment: Show your `saved` route code.

Comment: Just added it to the question

Comment: Do you use `body-parser` middleware to parse request body?

Comment: Yes. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Do I need to require body-parser in the test.js file as well?

Comment: No, you shouldn't require it in a test, but it should be required by app.js or server.js module, where you create and setup your app.